# optimizing indices with array math in F#

Tags: arrays, optimization, f#

I have code like this:

```
let mutable j = 0
while j < i - 1 do
    psi.[j] <- phi.[j]
    phi.[i - 1] <- phi.[i - 1] - psi.[j] * cov.[i - j - 1]
    j <- j + 1
```

Since the loop is moving through the arrays one element at a time, is there a way to make this faster in F#, like with incremented pointers in C/C++?

I'm assuming the indices will be recalculated at each iteration which is not ideal; and this code just one piece, there are a few pieces of code like this in a large loop.

Comment: What's your Benchmarkdotnet result, and did you check the binary JIT disassembly ? Typically such code gets optimized by JIT pretty well, and all calculations will be translated to their asm counterparts. You may be able to get rid of some bounds checks by initializing `i` as `Array.length`, but that's probably about it. With BDN you may check if loop unrolling helps, but this will be generally as fast as the same code in C#. You can rewrite it with pointers or spans, but it won't make it much faster, maybe a little. Measure on different systems, as caching and choice of JIT matters here.

Comment: Btw, this kind of micro-optimization rarely plays a big part in an application, be sure to carefully profile with a decent profiler to find real hot spots... Hmm, if you really want to squeeze every microsecond out of it, consider vectorization. Esp if you can rewrite it as unsigned ints, using 64, 128 or more bits may speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: The time this takes is very significant since a large part of history is taken into account to generate values (it's part of a fractional brownian motion system). It is used to generate test data in a loop and the generation takes about 20-25s on an i7 cpu; building the test data takes more than the actual test :) I'm questioning if doing this part in C may not be much faster than anything doable in F# just because it would be possible to skip the index calculations, but at the same time, the intel cpus support base + index * size as an addressing mode. You're right, I'll look at the JIT first

Comment: If you show some working code (current snippet is not complete) for which you're certain it's on the hot path, I can try help optimize it. Most likely, the biggest gain would be from vectorization, but that requires intricate knowledge of your algorithm.

Comment: I have put a the file here: https://pastebin.com/Lg3M2kxk and the project file here: https://pastebin.com/n6pmLKfB  It would be awesome if you could have a look! There is an unoptimized C version (I put the link in the file) but I am really curious if this can be done fast with F#

Comment: Thanks. I had a cursory look and there's a lot that can be optimized there, but it will take considerable time (ping me on F# Slack if you want to take this to its extreme). What I would do at the very least for quick-wins: (1) use `ArrayPool` to prevent zero-init of array, (2) use span or pointers to get rid of bounds checks, (3) remove duplication (`i - 1` can be lifted) (4) where possible, get rid of floats and use int or int64 (5) probably a lot more if I take a deep dive in the algorithm.

Comment: Have you considered using the SIMD suppport in .NET for this? `System.Numerics.Vectors` IIRC and there's also new intrinsic support for SIMD if you know what CPU brand you will be running on.

Comment: To avoid CPU stalling on the operations it could make a difference loading and operating on multiple samples in each loop. This could enable Out Of Order execution which in best case scenario gives 5-10x boost on mulitplication speed (but that is best case)

Comment: I will look this week at the algorithm to make sure it is as optimized as it can because there may be a couple shortcuts that will work in it. I haven't looked at system.numerics.vectors; the problem is that each result requires the previous one, so I'm not sure how SIMD would be useful in that case.